# How do you heal Mental Stress?

Tags: dresden-files, stress

Does the Recovery power only heal physical stress and not mental? Is there a way to heal mental stress besides taking a consequence?

Comment: what's the wording for the Recovery power?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All stress tracks (not just Mental) clear after a conflict ends. Unless you take consequences, which don't "heal" stress, but more **absorb** it, all your stress returns as soon as the conflict ends, as long as there's a reasonable opportunity to stop and take a breather.

It is possible to dive right from one conflict to another without a chance to rest. Just defeating a bad guy or whatever is not enough to trigger stress recovery. When wizards in my game are going from conflict to conflict with short rests, I try to decide if they have had enough time to unwind in between. I ask myself, "Is this next conflict a continuous event emotionally? Has there been another state of mind in between?"

I will have to check my book for the exact details on the Recovery power, but if memory serves, it's about Physical attributes, like Toughness and Might are.

Comment: Thanks!! How about healing consequences of the mental kind? like taking a mild for casting a boosted spell, can the Thaumaturgy Spell Reiki Healing Spell on page 300 heal it before we go to a new scene?

Comment: @RP21 - The circumstances under which I would allow a wizard to have a mental consequence healed by magic are practically nonexistent. Consequences take time to recover from. When I say to a player, "You could cast that spell if you take a consequence..." I'm asking, "How much is it worth to you?" I'm presenting an interesting, meaningful choice to player and character both. Take that away and it's just...flat.